# Problem when i try to use .add in a for Each (DART AND FLUTTER)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-html

i dont know what i do wrong

```
   Future<List<ProductoModel>> cargarProductos() async {
    final url = '$_url/productos.json';

    final resp = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    final Map<String, dynamic> decodeData = json.decode(resp.body);

    List produc = [];

    if (decodeData == null) return [];

    decodeData.forEach((id, prod) {
      final prodTemp = ProductoModel.fromJson(prod);
      prodTemp.id = id;
      produc.add(prodTemp);
      //print(produc); <-- if i print here work excelent

    });
    print(produc);  //<-- dont work , dont print nothing 

    return []; //<-- this line dont work too...
  }
```

as you see , the code dont print produc outside from the "forEch" (but work inside). The problem is that i want to return this produc in the widget  Future<List> cargarProductos()

Comment: does `produc.toString()` works, because it is a list now.  i would also check `print("product: ${produc.length} ${produc.toString()} ")`

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you set `produc` to `final`, which makes it immutable. You need to replace `final List produc = [];` with `List produc = [];`

Comment: I just tried running your code and it seems to work fine. Are you sure it isn't printing anything?

Comment: no , if i try inside the decodeData.forEach((id, prod) { pirnt(prodc)} works... but outside isnt work

Comment: can you paste the output with both `print` calls active?

Comment: bro literally below of decodeData.forEach dont print nothing ... (i mean dont return the print , and de return )

Comment: i have change the answer ... look , the return dont work and the print dosent work too

Comment: `final` prevents *reassignment*.  It does not make objects immutable.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are incorrect. The `final` keyword makes objects immutable, it doesn't just prevent reassignment. Check the documentation before you try to correct people

Comment: @PatrickMahomes Ironic that you are so quick to "correct" people.  If you don't believe me, try `final list = [1, 2, 3]; list.add(4); print(list);`.  [The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) additionally states: "**Note**: Although a `final` object cannot be modified, its fields can be changed. In comparison, a `const` object and its fields cannot be changed: they’re *immutable*." The wording should be improved, but it's stating that `const` objects are immutable, not `final` ones.

Comment: @jamesdlin ok, looks like I am wrong, but I am also confused now. Please help me to understand how we reconcile "cannot be modified" with "fields can be changed". If you change the fields of an object, haven't you modified it?

Comment: By "cannot be modified", the documentation means that the variable "cannot be modified to refer to another object".  In other words, it can't be reassigned.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you are also right about the poor wording: "You can’t change the value of a final variable" and "a final object cannot be modified" sound kind of like immutable to me. Guess I need to improve my comprehension